# How to move `n` number char <left> in vim command line?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, cursor-movement, cursor-motions, cursor

My init.vim code

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <F4> :RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt
```

**I want my cursor position to be exact** `31 times <left>` in command line. 
or after `~/Downloads/`

Like this 
[image]

PS: I got this idea from this shortcut `nmap <leader>s :%s/\<<C-r><C-w>\>/<C-r><C-w>/gI<Left><Left><Left>` 
here the cursor goes 3 char left in command line

but if i use `<left>` it will take **31 left's** in my init.vim code to go in that position 
I couldn't find any simple solution. Maybe you folks can help me out a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to tell vim to land the cursor at a particular place in the cmdline during a map, but there are a number of workarounds.

1. Direct positioning

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <F4> :RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt<c-r>=setcmdpos(getcmdpos()-31)[1]<cr>
```

You can use `setcmdpos()` to place the cursor anywhere on the cmdline in an expression.  The only trick here is to have it not enter any text by indexing `[1]` (which is invalid, and returns empty string).

2. Alternative to `<left>`

```
autocmd FileType cpp nnoremap <F4> :RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt<s-left><s-left><s-left><s-left><s-left><left>
```

`shift-left` moves more than left, thus you will need fewer movements.

3. Using `repeat()`

```
autocmd FileType cpp execute 'nnoremap <F4> :RunWithFile ~/Downloads/ > output.txt && cat output.txt' . repeat('<left>', 31)
```

You can create the sequence of `<left>`s with an expression using the expression register.  The map itself will still be quite ugly but the code is cleaner.

Comment: thanks @mass .. i tried and these code works fine just as i expected.. i'll use with the `<s-left>` one though

Comment: the third one seems to have a problem.. I'm using neovim v0.5 .. it shows `invalid arguments for function repeat`

Comment: @MegaBang thanks, fixed (in a somewhat different way, but which is more instructive)

Comment: there's a small bug though.. tried to fix it but this system doesn't let me.. there won't be a backtick here after closing bracket.. it will be just `repeat('<left>', 31)` ..  vim throws an erorr "invalid expressions: `"

Answer (score 1):

1. Normally prefer `:h ftplugin` over `autocmd FileType`. If still want `autocmd`, at least, put it into `augroup`.
2. Use `:h map-<buffer>` to define a local mapping. Otherwise it will affect all other buffers/windows too.
3. Typing `foo[cursor]bar` is as simple as `bar<C-B>foo`.

Comment: how can i get the normal order `foobar` (not `barfoo`)?

Comment: @MegaBang As I said, typing "bar" then get to line start then type "foo". Is there any problem with this?

Comment: i rewrote my code just like you said, it works like a charm... but i wonder if there's any straight-forward configuration `foo[cursor]bar`